# SFTP-Nodejs create folder in remote location

Tags: javascript, node.js, sftp, ftps

I had used the following node module for sftp implementation.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftps

My target is to create a folder in the remote location and save my file. In the see the available session( http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) in the documentation it shows mkdir as an option. But I have no idea how to use it. Kindly help me create a folder in remote location. I am new to server development and this confuses me. Or is it possible to create a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding the following lines to index.js of node modules worked.

```
FTP.prototype.mkdir = function (directory , mode) {
    return this.raw('mkdir '+mode+' '+directory)
 };
```

The function call in the program is as follows

```
 ftps.mkdir(path,['-p']).cd(path).addFile(file);
```

Comment: This works great. Makes me wonder why it's not a part of the original package.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be in the documentation but not in the actual source code *index.js*

You will have to use another libary.

Comment: Any suggestion on what library I can use for this? Iam not able to find a way o do it using sftp